# Unit Test Object Method With Promise and Proxyquire

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, chai

I have a User object which contains a method insert that returns a Promise.

```
insert() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (this.id){
            reject("This object is already inserted in base");
        }
        // Some things here
        console.log('Printing something here to test');
        // mysql.query('Some query')
        resolve(this);
        // Some things here
    }.bind(this));
}
```

I want to test that the promise is rejected if the User object already have an ID

I use for my test mocha, chai and chai-as-promised.

What I want is to proxyquire mysql.query so it returns a fix result, which works on other test cases. But now I precisely want to try that the insert method reject.

I tried to do that :

```
it("Inserting user with id should fail", () => { 
        const proxy = proxyquire.load('../models/Users', {
            './dbc': {
                query : function(query, args) {
                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        resolve({ insertId : 2});
                    })
                }
            }
        });

        var us = new proxy();
        us.id = 3;
        us.password = "test";
        us.username = "testLogin";
        us.mail = "testMail";
        us.isAdmin = "false";

        expect(us.insert()).to.be.rejected();

    });
```

What I don't understand :

- First my test failed telling me that :

it gives me this error :

TypeError: expect(...).to.be.rejected is not a function

But also, my console.log which happens after the reject is made and I can see it in the npm test result. Finally I also tried to put some log in the if to be sure that it wasn't the problem and actually it goes in the if, so it seems that the reject method is called but do nothing.

So I don't know, am I using promise in a wrong way ? Or is my way to test wrong ?

Comment: please try `to.be.rejected` (without parentheses)

Comment: That did the trick thanks ! :) However, I still need to do return after reject, is that normal ?

Comment: I believe you don't need to specify `return` statement after reject. Why do you need that?

Comment: That's Where it stranges, when I test it it goes  through the reject and also in the console log  which is after the reject. That's why I have to return after reject. Maybe it happened only when testing, i'll try later this day!